# How to route to a default action without it defined in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How do I produce this result?
www.domain.com/brand/brand-name
where 
brand = {controller}
parameter = {brand-name}

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Brand Details",
   url: "{controller}/{brandName}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Brand", action = "Index", brandName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

View: \Brand\Index.cshtml, which will be the default action result view.

I am getting a 404 error at this time.

Output expectation:
http://www.domain.com/brand => will not be allowed
http://www.domain.com/brand-name => will not be allowed
http://www.domain.com/brand/brand-name => will get details of brand-name and return view.

Comment: Try specifying `url: "Brand/{brandName}"` otherwise the routing is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should route like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Brand Details",
  url: "Brand/{brandName}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Brand", 
                  action = "Index", 
                  brandName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: That appeared to have work. Same with DavidG's comment. One additional step was to move this in the priority list with the other routes in place.

Comment: Remove the `/{action}` part and this answer is fine. Of course it's a copy of my comment but what the heck! Fix it and you get my upvote :)

Comment: @Rick Yes, I was going to mention putting this rule above the default one but was only writing a quick comment.

Comment: @DavidG Hmm, I can't seem to accept your comment as an answer. I would've given both credit.

Comment: I didn't write an answer, that's why. :)